# How to create an Ember JS Master Detail where detail appears between rows of data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a page that contains master/detail, which is obviously easy using a static {{ outlet }} in ember, however, I'd like the detail to slide down after the row that was selected. For example, on this page: http://jsbin.com/ijejap/1/edit, if the detail of the name was to appear after the currently selected name instead of at the bottom of the page.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I can't have an outlet within a repeater so that when I click Row 1, I want the outlet to be positioned below Row 1, and when I click Row 2, I want the outlet after Row 2.  In other words, I want to dynamically position an outlet, I think, unless there's another way to do it.

Comment: You are looking for animations at route transitions, right? Checkout liquid fire: https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally made a conditionnal outlet depending on wether the user is selected or not, but I had to work with `DS.Model` and its `FIXTURES` to make this work.

To be brief, I added an action before the link to set a `selected` property on the user object and record which user is selected to prevent having two users at the same time.

The position of the `{{outlet}}` then depends on the current selected user.

Here's the template part:

```
{{#each model}}
  <li {{action 'select' this}}>
    {{#link-to "user" this}}{{first}}{{/link-to}}
  </li>
  {{#if selected}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

And the `App.ApplicationController` part:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  currentUser: null,

  actions: {
    select: function(newUser) {
      var oldUser = this.get('currentUser');
      if(newUser !== oldUser) {
        if(oldUser)
          oldUser.toggleProperty('selected');
        this.set('currentUser', newUser);
        newUser.toggleProperty('selected');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, the model definition:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  first: DS.attr(),
  last: DS.attr(),
  avatar: DS.attr()
});
```

Here's the link to the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/cilari/3/

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great.  I'd never even though about adding the outlet multiple times in an if statement.  Excellent.

Comment: You're welcome. The important thing is to make sure that the outlet will never appear more than one time in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of components power here.

I made it on JSBin : http://jsbin.com/zovos/2/

First, you declare your user details as a new component, say user-details :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/user-details">
  <li>{{user.first}}</li>
  <h2>
    {{user.first}} {{user.last}}
    <img {{bindAttr src="user.avatar"}} class="pull-right" width=50 />
  </h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>First</dt>
    <dd>{{user.first}}</dd>
    <dt>Last</dt>
    <dd>{{user.last}}</dd>
  </dl>
</script>
```

Then you call it from your list, using the current user as the user in the component :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <ul class="nav nav-list span3 well">
        {{#each model}}
          {{user-details user=this}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

You add the `selected` property to your component and an action like `expandDetails` :

```
App.UserDetailsComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  selected: false,
  actions: {
    expandDetails: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, you add the action to your component template and a conditional display on the `selected` property :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/user-details">
  <li><a {{action "expandDetails"}}>{{user.first}}</a></li>
  {{#if selected}}
    <h2>
      {{user.first}} {{user.last}}
      ...
    </dl>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

And, of course, you get rid of your user route.

Here is a link to Ember's Guide that show this on a sample post example : http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is useful and is the way that I've currently implemented this, but I'm looking for a way to link a route to this detail component, as having a URL directly to the sub route is important to my application.

Comment: Take a look at "Query Params", this is a way to make the URL change depending on which is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an accordion?

http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-widgets/accordion

Comment: Hi, the accordion itself may well be the UI element I want to show the element, but what I also want is for the content of the accordion to be it's own controller etc.

Comment: You may want to use a partial in the each block for the user

`{{#each model}}<li>{{partial "user"}}</li>{{/each}}`

If you want to specify a controller and a model and a template, use render instead.

Comment: I guess the problem is that I need a route for the row detail, as I'd like to be able to have a url attached to the detail.  From what I understand, partials are just dropped in place without changing context, and render is the same?

Comment: @Deeksy I've actually done something like this with itemController, where each item was also a link-to. I basically render everything (master and detail), but I hide detail with CSS unless that route is active.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but unproved yet, maybe you can try it.

1. For detail, you only need one template. For master, you need write several named outlet (see: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) and place each below the corresponding item of master view.
2. When each master item has been clicked, you need pass a param to the detail route in order to let it know what kind of data should be populated.
3. The key part is the `renderTemplate` hook of route (see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate). You can take advantage of it because it allows you to specify which named outlet should be used to render the template.

Or you may load all details' data at once and cache it, then pass an identifier when master item got clicked, in this way you can filter the model in advance and get prepared for later `renderTemplate` use.

This is just an idea and currently don't have spare time to try it, but as your wish, you got the dedicated route, controller and model. I think it is highly doable, let me know it you make any progress.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable way to do this, as I can create a number of outlets, but the problem is I can't have dynamic outlet names, so that when I have 10 rows, for example, it's not possible to have outlets referenced by ID, for example.  Guess I'll have to re-think the problem.